# what's the max size of a url word in a URL?

Tags: url, seo

i was wondering, in order to get a good SEO you have to use natural language in your URLs.
Do you know the max size for a word or phrase in characters?
ex:

```
www.me.com/this-is-a-really-long-url.htm
```

i ask this, because once i've checked out that google was banning some of my URLs because they were too long.
thanks a lot :D

Comment: A question for http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you link to that information because I guess the SEO limit is more on the total length than the individual parts.

When generating friendly URLs, try to keep below 15 chars for sections, 40 chars for article and a couple more for id.

Also, try to use subdomains if available, you can link them in your Google panel anyway

That is: 
http://forums.en.mycompany.com/general/annoucements/5142-today-is-a-big-day.html

Answer (score 0):

There is no limitation on the url length as of now. you can keep as long as you wish, but that doesnot bring you any positive affect or SEO friendly.

So it is advisable not to exceed more than 90 characters